# Why do lp and lpr return unauthorized error?

Tags: printing

So my questions are:

What would cause lp or lpr to return Unauthorized?

What can I do to fix this problem?

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with latest updates. This worked and then stopped after an update. The problem is I don't remember when it stopped. My user is part of lpadmin, which allows me to create and configure printers through the CUPS interface.

Here are my system's protections for `lp` and `lpr`.

```
root@steamboy:/usr/bin# ls -l lp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13540 2011-09-12 10:41 lp

root@steamboy:/usr/bin# ls -l lpr
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13540 2011-09-12 10:41 lpr
```

Only if I sudo can I print something at the command line using `lp` or `lpr`.

```
ics@steamboy:~/icsdev$ lp x.tmp
lp: Unauthorized
ics@steamboy:~/icsdev$ lpr x.tmp
lpr: Unauthorized
```

(`x.tmp` is a real file.)

Comment: Maybe the user are blocked from using the printer.

Comment: I've edited the original post. This happened after an update. I know of no printer blocked list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that might be worth trying is:

```
sudo apt-get purge cups
```

That will not only uninstall cups but also delete its configuration files in case one of them is wrong.

Then:

```
sudo apt-get install cups
```

Since the configuration files are now fresh you will have to reinstall your printers. If you use any other computer as a print server you may have to do this there as well.

[This](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/network-internet/464929-network-printer-issues.html) opensuse link describes what another user had to do to one of his cups configuration files to solve this error message.

Comment: I see you have been struggling with this for quite a while.

Comment: I'll also give this a shot Monday. Thanks again, again.

Comment: Excellent. Glad to hear it.

Comment: I've spread the info far and wide, referencing this post.

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue nowadays; after a purge and reinstall, the problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling and installing cups does NOT cure it. What if you had 50 printers?

In `/etc/cups/printers.conf` look for `AuthInfoRequired` it is probably set to `negotiate`.

There are numerous ways to change this but I do this

```
/etc/init.d/cups stop
vim /etc/cups/printers.conf
```

Remove the line with `negotiate` in it

```
/etc/init.d/cups start
```

Comment: In my case, `AuthInfoRequired` is set to `none` and I still have this problem.