# How can I get lp and lpr to run as if I were root?

Tags: printing

This post is related to [Why do lp and lpr return unauthorized error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147940/why-do-lp-and-lpr-return-unauthorized-error) However, I am asking this question to find a workaround to my problem.

I can use lp and lpr using sudo. I'd like to know how I can change permissions, so applications can run lp and lpr as if they were root. For that matter, I'd like to be able to do the same thing.

I've entered a bug on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/972434) to cover this, but have not heard back.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume this relates to launchpad bug 955103, as well. There the error log lists pairs of:
E [14/Mar/2012:07:38:14 -0400] [cups-polld 10.100.0.100:631] Unable to connect to 10.100.0.100 on port 631: Connection refused
E [14/Mar/2012:07:38:14 -0400] [cups-polld 10.100.0.71:631] Unable to connect to 10.100.0.71 on port 631: Connection refused

Are these both addresses of the computer you are doing the `lp` and `lpr` commands from, printer servers, or something else? Can you connect to to 10.100.0.100:631 and 10.100.0.71:631 from your browser?

Comment: That may be part of search in CUPS. I can print as root, but not as myself. I'd like to be able to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what is causing your problem it's hard to devise a good workaround.

I should add that I'm not sure applications normally execute the lp or lpr commands in order to print. I assume they use a library interface. An example would be [this](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/gtk3-High-level-Printing-API.html).

While it's not recommended for security reasons, you can set permissions so that when you run lpr or lp command, they run with the same permission as the user-id they belong to or the group they belong to (root):

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/bin/lp /usr/bin/lpr
```

Whether or not it helps applications print it should help you use these commands without using sudo each time, assuming you decide to bear the risk. Wikipedia mentions those risks, and a reference, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid).

Comment: However Acrobat Reader (Linux) and some other appications print, they are not able to print. But gnome-edit and Evolution can. Again, this happened after an update. I will try your suggestion Monday and report back. Thanks again.